# Checking the number of appearances of bigrams in list of list of words

Tags: python

I am trying to count the number of appearances for each unique bigram in a list of list of words. While also keeping track of unique unigrams.

For example, if i have a list:

```
[['like','this','movie'], ['i','fall','like','this']]
```

I have the bigrams `['like','this],['this','movie]` and so forth.

The bigram `['like','this']` appears twice so I want to create a data structure (a dict?) that keeps track of the bigram (the key) and the times it appeared (which is 2). Meanwhile, I also want to be keeping track of unique unigrams and the number of times they appear as well. What is the most efficient way to do this without looping over the list twice? Thanks!

Comment: thanks for editing sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

You can make your bigrams using `zip(l, l[1:])`, which will give you consecutive pairs. With the help of `chain.from_iterabl()` you can stream that right into a `Counter` to get the counts of pairs:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

l = [['like','this','movie'], ['i','fall','like','this']]

Counter(chain.from_iterable(zip(sublist, sublist[1:]) for sublist in l))
```

**Result**:

```
Counter({('like', 'this'): 2,
         ('this', 'movie'): 1,
         ('i', 'fall'): 1,
         ('fall', 'like'): 1})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! If I do this I would need to go through the list again to find all the unigrams correct? Is there a way I could iterate through both simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Counter in one pass using an internal list comprehension for the unigram and bigram:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [['like','this','movie'], ['i','fall','like','this']]

nGrams = Counter(gram for sl in l for a,b in zip(sl,sl[1:]+[""]) 
                      for gram in [(a,b),a][not b:])
```

result:

```
Counter({('like', 'this'): 2, 'like': 2, 'this': 2, 
         ('this', 'movie'): 1, 'movie': 1, 
         ('i', 'fall'): 1, 'i': 1, 
         ('fall', 'like'): 1, 'fall': 1})
```

You could even generalize it to any size of nGrams like this:

```
maxSize = 4
nGrams = Counter(gram for sl in l for w in zip(*(sl[s:]+[""]*s for s in range(maxSize)))
                      for gram in [w[:s+1] for s in range(maxSize)][:maxSize-w.count("")])
```

result:

```
Counter({('like',): 2, ('like', 'this'): 2, ('this',): 2, 
         ('like', 'this', 'movie'): 1, ('this', 'movie'): 1, 
         ('movie',): 1, ('i',): 1, ('i', 'fall'): 1, 
         ('i', 'fall', 'like'): 1, ('i', 'fall', 'like', 'this'): 1,
         ('fall',): 1, ('fall', 'like'): 1, 
         ('fall', 'like', 'this'): 1})
```